# MS Excel -Finding merged cells & combining info in them at corresponding row

Tags: vba, excel, merge, excel-formula

[image]

There are some merged and some unmerged cells in column A, of different sizes, and column B is made up of all unmerged cells.

I am looking for a formula (if none exists, that could be written with VBA), that would determine whether a cell is merged or unmerged in A, and if it is merged, combine the components in column B (like the formula concatenate does) and write it to one of the rows of it, say the upper one, and if possible delete the row below.

Can I do this with a formula, can anyone help me with a given code, please?

---

[image: PART II]

Now I want to not lose the data of the given rows, but add the data in 3rd and 4th columns between themselves as shown in the figure. And make the stars disappear if possible.

Comment: You'll need to use VBa.  What have you tried already? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to make a function on VBA that would determine the merged cells at first. But I don't really know how to do it. I found this formula in an external web site:                                                                              Sub FindMerged1()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      If c.MergeCells Then
      MsgBox c.Address & " is merged"
      End If
    Next
End Sub                                                                                                                And tried to change the MsgBox row with a function, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it quick and simple: (put this in any module in your VBA window)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function merge_merged(rng As Range) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, output() As Variant
  ReDim output(1 To UBound(rng.Value), 1 To 2)
  For j = 1 To UBound(rng.Value)
    If Len(rng(j, 1).Text) Then
      i = i + 1
      output(i, 1) = rng(j, 1).Text
      output(i, 2) = rng(j, 2).Text
    Else
      output(i, 2) = output(i, 2) & ", " & rng(j, 2).Text
    End If
  Next
  For i = i + 1 To j - 1
    output(i, 1) = ""
    output(i, 2) = ""
  Next
  merge_merged = output
End Function
```

then select the range D2:E13 and use the formula

```
=merge_merged(B2:C13)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

should do exactly what you asked for... If you still have any questions, just write a comment

Also works with strings for me:
[image]

**EDIT**:

You should not change the Question after you got the answer you desired, better ask a new one. Still, I will provide a solution this time:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function merge_merged(rngIn As Range) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, output() As Variant, rng As Variant
  rng = rngIn.Value
  ReDim output(1 To UBound(rng), 1 To UBound(rng, 2))
  For j = 1 To UBound(rng)
    If Len(rng(j, 1)) Then
      i = i + 1
      For k = 1 To UBound(output, 2)
        If IsNumeric(Replace(rng(j, k), "*", "")) Then
          output(i, k) = Replace(rng(j, k), "*", "")
        Else
          output(i, k) = rng(j, k)
        End If
      Next
    Else
      For k = 1 To UBound(output, 2)
        If Len(rng(j, k)) Then
          If IsNumeric(output(i, k)) And IsNumeric(Replace(rng(j, k), "*", "")) Then
            output(i, k) = 0 + output(i, k) + Replace(rng(j, k), "*", "")
          Else
            output(i, k) = output(i, k) & ", " & rng(j, k)
          End If
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
  For i = i + 1 To j - 1
    For k = 1 To UBound(output, 2)
      output(i, k) = ""
    Next
  Next
  merge_merged = output
End Function
```

[image]

- only the first column will be checked for collapsing
- if column "2" to "end" contain numbers, they will be summed up

  - *having mixed values (numerical and strings) may mess up*

    - "A", "3", "5" will be "A, 3, 5"
    - "3", "A", "5" will be "3, A, 5"
    - but "3", "5", "A" will be "8, A"
  - `*` will be deleted if the string is numerical without it
- it will pull all values of the first row (for each merged part)

  - if there is no "first" value, the first found will be shown as ", value"
  - if all cells are empty, the output will also be empty
- empty cells will be ignored ("A", "", "C" will become "A, C")
- pushed everything in a variable to be fast for bigger tables

Comment: But when I implemented this function to my original cells with actual words (multiple words in each cell to be more spesific), and with no numbers, it didn't work. Is it related with the types of the variables in the code? How can I fix this?

Comment: @heyy the type doesn't matter... should work also with any type of string (added a pic to my answer)

Comment: @DirkReichel I found out the problem, it was related with the type of the file. Now can you also help with the second part on this code as I edited above (since this is the only one which worked for my data&computer) I tried to add in the VBA file but it did not work again.

Comment: @heyy Added the feature you requested just this one time ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to "Unmerge" the cells first, then use collections to get the unique values and create a loop.

```
 Sub uNMERGE()
    Dim rng As Range, lstRw As Long, c As Range

    Columns("A:A").MergeCells = 0

    lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & lstRw)

    For Each c In rng.Cells

        If c = "" Then
            c = c.Offset(-1)
        End If

    Next c

    UsingColection
End Sub
Sub UsingColection()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant
    Dim rws As Long, s As String

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    rws = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A" & rws)
    Set cUnique = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In rng.Cells
        cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each vNum In cUnique
        Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = vNum

        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c = vNum Then
                s = s & c.Offset(, 1) & ","
            End If
        Next c

        Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Mid(s, 1, Len(s) - 1)
        s = ""

    Next vNum

End Sub
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

Comment: Might need a `dim rws As Long, s As String` in the UsingColection sub.

Comment: How should I call the function?

Comment: Just run uNMERGE() macro

Answer (score 2):

Rather than dealing with the [Range.MergeArea property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822300.aspx), it is probably better to simply [Range.UnMerge method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210014%28v=office.12%29.aspx) the offending cells and deal with the resulting blanks differently than the one that remained populated.

```
Sub flatten_merge()
    Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(1).UnMerge
        ReDim vVALs(1 To Application.Count(.Columns(1)), 1 To 2)
        For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, 1)) Then
                vVALs(v, 2) = vVALs(v, 2) & Chr(44) & .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
            Else
                v = v + 1
                vVALs(v, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                vVALs(v, 2) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
            End If
        Next rw
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs
    End With
End Sub
```

If you have a need to retain the original(s), then a simple modification to copy the source to a new location would suffice.

Sample data and results:

[image: flatten_table_unmerge]     [image: flatten_table_unmerge_results]
                 <sup>Before</sup>                               <sup>After</sup>

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned words, not numbers, in another comment. In that case, the `application.count` should be `application.counta` .

Answer (score 2):

additional variant to already posted:

```
Sub tets()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range, k, s%
    Dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Set Data = Range("A1:A" & [A:A].Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
    For Each cl In Data
       If cl.Value2 <> "" Then s = cl.Value2
        If Not Dic.exists(s) Then
            Dic.Add s, cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        Else
            Dic(s) = Dic(s) & "," & cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        End If
    Next cl
    For Each k In Dic
        Debug.Print k, Dic(k)
    Next k
End Sub
```

**test**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So what is wrong with this code? -Since it gives #VALUE! error at every cell selected.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function merge_merged(rng As Range) As Variant

  Dim i As Long, j As Long, output() As Variant
  ReDim output(1 To UBound(rng.Value), 1 To 4)
  For j = 1 To UBound(rng.Value)
    If Len(rng(j, 1).Text) Then
      i = i + 1
      output(i, 1) = rng(j, 1).Text
      output(i, 2) = rng(j, 2).Text
      output(i, 3) = rng(j, 3).Value
      output(i, 4) = rng(j, 4).Value
      output(i, 5) = rng(j, 5).Text

    Else
      output(i, 2) = output(i, 2) & ", " & rng(j, 2).Text
      output(i, 3) = output(i, 3) + rng(j, 3).Value
      output(i, 4) = output(i, 4) + rng(j, 4).Value
      output(i, 5) = rng(j, 5).Text
    End If
  Next
  For i = i To j - 1
    output(i, 1) = ""
    output(i, 2) = ""
    output(i, 3) = ""
    output(i, 4) = ""
    output(i, 5) = ""
  Next
  merge_merged = output
End Function
Sub ece()
End Sub
```

And what else can I do to search for "star"s? And create a new column to refer if data in each cell (even if once merged) had "star"s?